# Big list of beautifully typeset package documentations

Tags: typography, documentation, big-list

Being just a LaTeX user, I have to look up documentation very often. What could be easier than `texdoc packagename` and here it is.

The other day I opened for curiosity the [`scontents`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scontents) package and was taken aback how -- how to express that in English? -- »intricate« the manual had been typeset.

The beautifully typeset documentations may serve as good use cases for people in search of inspiration.

So I'm asking you to say which package documentation you found outstanding in design and typesetting.

Comment: `tikzducks` has some wonderful graphics. Also I think `ducksay`'s duckumentation looks good, but I might be biased on that one.

Comment: @Skillmon So go ahead and write an answer with your favourites!

Comment: [`tasks`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks) or any other [Clemmens Niederberger's](https://ctan.org/author/niederberger) package.

Comment: @Ignasi Seems I have to answer my question myself with all the glorious suggestions from the comments!

Comment: When you do it, don't forget to mention André Miede's [ClassicThesis](https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) and Lorenzo Pantieri's rework of it on [ArsClassica](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arsclassica)

Comment: Since this is prone to be opinion based and not really answerable, I think this should be a community wiki question.

Comment: @KeksDose: Mmm, `scontents` "intricate", of all the documentations that I have reviewed in my free time the ones that most please me are those of `tabu` (and the rest of Florent Chervet's packages) and that of `xwatemark` (and the rest of Ahmed Musa's packages), I have guided myself by them to write `scontents`.

Comment: For sure, `tcolorbox`.

Comment: I think the `arara` manual should also be.

Comment: The `babel` manual. And the `texapi` manual.

Answer (score 4):

I find it pleasing and enthralling every time the documentation of a package implicitly makes use of some of its own features, thereby whetting my appetite *en passant* so to speak. Perhaps this is the opposite of some sort of performative contradiction, maybe one can call it performative congruence? However, two of my stars are the following:

– [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype). One of my favorite packages; apart from being well structured and comprehensive, the documentation is also extremely neatly typeset due to its own features! It shows implicitly what the package is supposed to support!

– [selnolig](https://ctan.org/pkg/selnolig?lang=de). Same here. The package supports selective suppression of ligatures with a few simple key-strokes. By employing a wide array of ligatures in different languages throughout the document, one becomes acutely aware what is possible with ligatures in the first place!